# classes vs modules in Ruby: ho to manage a lot of instance methods ?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, methods, scope, namespaces

I'm working on a chatbot dialog manager, where a dialog is kindof an aggregation of many dialogs (where a dialog is a set of methods).

The first approach is to have a Dialog class that include methods "encapsulated" in modules:

```
# file dialog1.rb
module Dialog1
  def method1_1
    puts 'method1_1'
  end
  def method1_2
    puts 'method1_2'
  end
  def method_common
    puts 'method_common_1'
  end
  def method1_N
    # ...
  end
end

# file dialog2.rb
module Dialog2
  def method2_1
    puts 'method2_1'
  end
  def method_common
    puts 'method_common_2'
  end
  def method2_M
    # ...
  end
end

require 'file1'
require 'file2'
# ...

class Dialog   
  include Dialog1
  include Dialog2
  # ... 
end
```

I'm perplex and I do not like too much this solution; in this way I have possible duplicate methods side effects ( In Ruby duplicated methods are allowed :( ); by example in case of `method_common` method:

```
dialog = Dialog.new.method_common
# method_common_2
```

Maybe a reenigineering with classes could be better. 
What I'd prefer is to have the Dialog instance as a full join ("aggregation") of methods of all dialogs, but I don't know how to implement it. Any idea ?

Comment: using classes instead of modules won't improve the situation with duplicated methods. Something else is needed. It's hard to say what exactly, though, as we don't know this app.

Comment: Perhaps giving an actual example of the two classes that you plan to combine would help others give the best solution.

Comment: From your description it's not obvious why you're using methods - looks like some DSL or data files (text, json, etc) and their handlers bring the same results in a more pleasant way.

Comment: yes, you are right Vladimir, all.  I claimed to use def in modules, avoiding creation of new instances of classes in run time (for performances reason), but in facts in Ruby is more pleasant / correct to use classes inheritance and instances with a maybe lack of performnaces; I'm rengineering in this way